# Contar registros de una subconsulta en oracle 18c

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

Amigos buenos dias, tengo un problema y espero puedan ayudarme por favor tengo una consulta que ya logré hacer, basicamente me trae los registros que no están de una tabla a otra, es decir la problematica es  necesito es saber cuantos datos del INSTALLMENT_INST_ID  existen en la tabla PE_INSTALL,MENT_DETAIL  que no existan en la PE_INSTALLMENT_INST , anexo código:

Nota: cambié el codigo, anexo el actualizado

```
SELECT distinct INSTALLMENT_INST_ID FROM PE_INSTALLMENT_DETAIL t1
    where INSTALLMENT_INST_ID not in (select INSTALLMENT_INST_ID from 
                                     PE_INSTALLMENT_INST t2
                                        where t2.INSTALLMENT_INST_ID = 
                                        t1.INSTALLMENT_INST_ID)
```

Lo que ahora requiero es traerme todos los registros en ya no solo ser una columna sino como un select * from table por ejm, espero y puedan ayudarme y quedo al pendiente y si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto lo aclararé, saludos

Nota mas, es buena practica dejarlo así con esa condición en el not in o hay alguna forma de arreglarlo bien?

Comment: puedes usar simplemente `count(*)` y  una resta :v

Comment: Hola ya actualicé mi pregunta amigo